# Applescript Repeat Loop Not Returning Expected Results

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I am trying to "find-replace" a series of superscript cross-reference letters with numbers in Adobe InDesign. I have two "hard-coded" lists

set myLetters to {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}
set myNumbers to {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"}

It seems fairly straightforward but the script changes all of the occurrences to "1" on the first iteration and thus all subsequent replaces are ignored because the find is "false"

Any help and insight would be very much appreciated.

Here is the script as written:

tell application "Adobe InDesign 2023"

```
set myDocument to document 1

set include footnotes of find change text options to false
set include hidden layers of find change text options to false
set include locked layers for find of find change text options to false
set include locked stories for find of find change text options to false
set include master pages of find change text options to false
set whole word of find change text options to false
set case sensitive of find change text options to true
set search backwards of find change text options to false

set find text preferences to nothing
set change text preferences to nothing

set mySelection to selection

tell myDocument
    set myCharacterStyle to object reference of character style "sup" of character style group "Cross References"
end tell

set myLetters to {"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"}
set myNumbers to {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15"}

repeat with i from 1 to count of myLetters
    set find what of find text preferences to item i of myLetters
    set applied character style of find text preferences to myCharacterStyle
    set change to of change text preferences to item i of myNumbers
    change text mySelection
end repeat
```

end tell

Comment: Don't have ID so I can't see what all the options are but it looks like your script is doing a batch replace, i.e. 'replace all', the first time through. Is there not an option to do the equivalent of a single 'replace '? If not, you may have to craft another solution. Separately, are the various settings you make (codes line 2-9) not part of the 'find/change text preferences'? If so, don't code lines 10-11 remove all of your settings?

Comment: Once you've changed all of the "a" to "1", future attempts to find "a" will fail because you've just turned them all into "1"

Comment: Thanks Mockman for the hint on what the problem was: revising the "change" command to "tell item i of myFind to change text" the wholesale change was eliminated and script returned expected results.